# tomcat ssl configuration in port 443

Tags: ssl, tomcat

I am trying to configure ssl into my web app. Generated the .jks file from .cer file using java keytool and configured it in server.xml

But Tomcat refuses to start in port 443 or port 8443 after this configuration.

**server.xml**

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" connectionTimeout="20000" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" keystoreFile="/home/file.jks" keystorePass="****" />
```

and

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" connectionTimeout="20000" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" keystoreFile="/home/file.jks" keystorePass="****" />
```

**URL used in browser:**

```
    https://10.111.77.66/MY-APP

and    https://10.111.77.66:8443/MY-APP
```

Both URL not working.

**Error message in Browser:**

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection

10.111.77.66 uses an unsupported protocol.


ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
```

Before SSL configuration, Application was running fine in port 8082. ( `http://10.111.77.66:8082/MY-APP` )

What is wrong here? Stuck up badly. Please help.

**Server is Linux.**

**Tomcat Logs:**

```
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:455)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:447)

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-443]]

 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-443]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:568)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
```

Comment: Please, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65787233/edit) your question and add the system you are using (UNIX-es allow only `root` to bind port `443`) together with the log lines concerning the `https-jsse-nio-443` connector (look in the `catalina.<date>.log` file). Also this kind of questions are better suited for [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: My guess is you get a _"permission denied"_ while binding the socket (only root can bind port 443). If that's the case, check [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1006266/530633) or any of [these answers](https://serverfault.com/search?q=%5Btomcat%5D+privileged+port).

Comment: I'm thinking about "Generated the .jks file from .cer file" - does this jks include the private key which isn't in the .cer?

Comment: @Piotr P. Karwasz, Your  guess was right . Permission is denied. Have pasted the logs above. The idea is to run the app on https rather on http. How can I make this now?

Comment: @piet.t , Yes I had the private key ( .p7b file) but didn't use it during generation of keystore. I only used .cer file. Should I use .p7b file?  If yes how ?

Comment: Check the links above: Tomcat needs the `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` capability or equivalent (authbind). How to achieve that easily depends on your distribution: e.g. the `tomcat9` package on Debian 10 has it out-of-the-box.

Comment: I have RHEL 8.2 and tomcat 8 running. Can you send me a suitable link with procedures?